# Could not yum update on CentOS8 manual install, but browser has internet connected

Tags: yum, centos8

```
[root@localhost san]# yum update
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:30    
CentOS-8 - Base                                 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:30    
CentOS-8 - Extras                               0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:30    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'AppStream', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'BaseOS', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'extras', ignoring this repo.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
[root@localhost san]#
```

Comment: Have you tried `yum clean all` then `yum update`?

Answer (score 0):

proxy was the issue! forgot to add proxy for all bash users